# Some clarification on Regex

Tags: regex, ubuntu, grep

I am using the grep regex to match a string exceeding say 150 characters without spaces.
The regex I am using in command line in Ubuntu is like this:

Option1:

`grep -rle '[^\ ]\{150,\}'  --include=\*.php --exclude-dir=cache`

Option2

`grep -rl --include=\*.php --exclude-dir=cache '[^\ ]\{150,\}'`

Now with the commands I get the results, but not exactly I expect it to,
for example When I try

Option3

`grep -rle 'base64_decode'  --include=\*.php --exclude-dir=cache`

I get a result list of file say malicious.php
the contents of which looks like this:

```
'LqOC1ZYpuMOpuhuBTmNJrNmCKMiRkMQp68rRkMG2bfuaTmNJrNmpL8GKknNRb8QRAYy2K3PhHtEHt'.
'SNCLfOp68QsKjYpYZxz6ZisHDqaUea3AYF28Z7CK3PML1xc5ZYc'.
'A8WsKnNRLfQsAYyClpehHtEHDNNC0mPs68ipLYORYZWRL1rzKMYa5SgV5Zbn8MUlVZJBHmu'
```

my question is why this the file malicous.php is not listed with the regex option1 and option2.
what will be the correct regex to list the malicious.php specifying greater than `n` number of characters without spaces.

Comment: correct `regex` in terms of what? Do the `regex` have different outputs?

Comment: to find a string like the example I have give with the number of characters in regex instead of specifying the part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for me what worked correctly was the regex as below, which will exclude only horizontal space, but not the vertical space.

Which in effect will match the string example given in the question.

`grep -rle '[^\h]\{150,\}'  --include=\*.php --exclude-dir=cache`